# Add an Item in OrderedMap with Immutable.js

Tags: immutable.js

How can I add an Item at the end of an OrderedMap ?

I tried

```
    this.boxes = this.boxes.setIn(data);
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way of doing it is using [concat](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedMap/concat)

```
var boxes = Immutable.OrderedMap({
  box1: {
    id:1
  },
  box2: {
    id:2
  }
});

var data = Immutable.fromJS({
  box3: {
    id:3
  }
});


var newBoxes = boxes.concat(data);
console.log(newBoxes.toJS());
```

Will print out:

> Object {   box1: Object {
>       id: 1   },   box2: Object {
>       id: 2   },   box3: Object {
>       id: 3   } }

Answer (score 3):

An OrderedMap doesn't really have an "end" per se. Also if you want to add an item to a Map you're going to need a key for it as well.
So either you use the `set` method for adding a key-value pair:

```
this.boxes = this.boxes.set(key,data);
```

Or you convert it to a List, where you can add it to the end and also maintain a clear iteration order, meaning you do get to have an "end".

```
this.boxes = this.boxes.toList().push(data);
```