# How to add key value pair as last entry in OrderedMap..?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js, ordered-map

Possible duplicate:
[Add an Item in OrderedMap with Immutable.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35946015/add-an-item-in-orderedmap-with-immutable-js)

Working with **redux store** and **Immutable js** [OrderedMap](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedMap).

**Redux store structure:**

```
   {
     "app": {
        "name": "Test app",
        "dataPack":{
          "chemID": "aaaa",
          "item": {
            "yp57m359": {
            "solid": 33,
            "liquid": 45,
            "gas": 65
           },
           "h58wme1y": {
             "solid": 87,
             "liquid": 9,
             "gas": 30
           },
           "dff56fhh": {
             "solid": 76,
             "liquid": 43,
             "gas": 77
           }
         }
       }
     }
  }
```

**Reducer code:**

```
return state.setIn(["app","dataPack","item",action.item_id],
  fromJS({
    "solid": action.soildVal,
    "liquid": action.liquidVal,
    "gas": action.gasVal
}));
```

where `action.item_id` is the random id (key for every item).

Above code works perfectly for adding items.

**Problem is:** Items stored in a random position. I need to keep the order I am adding. Need to add every item as **last entry** inside `item`. Adding one by one item is not in same order.

Help me to get a clear solution for this.

Comment: Can't you just use a [`List`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/List)?

Comment: Is it possible to add key value pair without array index in `List` as showed in my store structure.?

Comment: No, but in which language do you have the support that you wish? Why not add the keyvaluepair as an item of your list?

Comment: I am working in Immutable js OrderedMap, i need only key value pairs, not array. Can you suggest me how to insert values in last position in OrderedMap..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `OrderedMap` will remember the order you put things in it. Every time you call `.set(key, value)` with a new `key` on an OrderedMap, it will get added to the end.

```js
let state = Immutable.Map({
  "app": Immutable.Map({
    "name": "Test App",
    "dataPack": Immutable.Map({
      "chemId": "aaaa",
      "items": Immutable.OrderedMap({}) // this is the thing we want ordered
    })
  })
});

state = state.setIn(['app', 'dataPack', 'items', 'yp57m359'], Immutable.Map({
  'first': 'item'
}));
state = state.setIn(['app', 'dataPack', 'items', 'h58wme1y'], Immutable.Map({
  'second': 'item'
}));
state = state.setIn(['app', 'dataPack', 'items', 'dff56fhh'], Immutable.Map({
  'third': 'item'
}));


console.log(state.toJS()); // notice things are in order
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.js"></script>
```

It's hard to tell exactly where your problem is because we can't see how you created your store, but my guess would be that `"item"` is pointing to a regular old `Map` instead of an `OrderedMap`. If you're just using `fromJS(data)` to create your state, it will default to using a `Map` instead of an `OrderedMap`.

Comment: Yes you are correct.. Its(`items` key) showing as `Map` when i console it.

**Below is the `Reducer` code i have used to set whole state as OrderedMap:**

    `import {OrderedMap, fromJS} from 'immutable';
    export default function myApp(state = new OrderedMap, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_DATA':
          return fromJS({app:action.data.app});
        case 'TEST_DATA':
          console.log(state);
      }
    }`

Eventhough its showing as `Map`.
Can you assist me how to set `item` key as OrderedMap..?